# ExtJS5 Charts Show Tooltips at all Times

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs5

In Ext JS 5, how do I get charts to always show tool tips? I want to have one tool tip that shows per each month line on the x axis in the chart.  The listener event would be moving the mouse over a new month point but extend all the way up the y axis of the month highlighted.  It would follow the mouse and update when you moved the mouse from x axis point to x axis point and show on the y axis line.

Right now all I can get it to do is show the tool tip on hover of the actual line itself.

I tried iteminfo as an interaction but that did nothing. Couldn't find a working example of this not in Touch online either:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/deh

```js
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    layout: 'fit',
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: ['->', {
            text: 'Preview',
            handler: function(button) {
                button.up('panel').down('cartesian').preview();
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Download',
            handler: function(button) {
                button.up('panel').down('cartesian').download();
            }
        }]
    }],
    items: [{
        xtype: 'cartesian',
        highlight: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: 500,
        legend: {
            docked: 'right'
        },

        store: getStore(),
        insetPadding: 40,
        interactions: [{
            type: 'itemhighlight'
        }, {
            type: 'crosszoom'
        }],
        sprites: [{
            type: 'text',
            text: 'Line Charts - Marked Lines',
            font: '22px Helvetica',
            width: 100,
            height: 30,
            x: 40, // the sprite x position
            y: 20 // the sprite y position
        }],
        axes: [{
            type: 'numeric',
            fields: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4'],
            position: 'left',
            grid: true,
            minimum: 0,
            renderer: function(v) {
                return v.toFixed(v < 10 ? 1 : 0) + '%';
            }
        }, {
            type: 'category',
            fields: 'month',
            position: 'bottom',
            grid: true,
            label: {
                rotate: {
                    degrees: -45
                }
            }
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            axis: 'left',
            title: 'IE',
            xField: 'month',
            yField: 'data1',
            style: {
                lineWidth: 4
            },
            marker: {
                radius: 5
            },
            highlight: {
                fillStyle: '#000',
                radius: 5,
                lineWidth: 2,
                strokeStyle: '#fff'
            },
            tooltip: {
                trackMouse: true,
                style: 'background: #fff',
                renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                    var title = item.series.getTitle();
                    this.setHtml(title + ' for ' + storeItem.get('month')
                        + ': ' + storeItem.get(item.series.getYField()) + '%');
                }
            }
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            axis: 'left',
            title: 'Firefox',
            xField: 'month',
            yField: 'data2',
            style: {
                lineWidth: 4
            },
            marker: {
                radius: 4
            },
            highlight: {
                fillStyle: '#000',
                radius: 5,
                lineWidth: 2,
                strokeStyle: '#fff'
            },
            tooltip: {
                trackMouse: true,
                style: 'background: #fff',
                renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                    var title = item.series.getTitle();
                    this.setHtml(title + ' for ' + storeItem.get('month')
                        + ': ' + storeItem.get(item.series.getYField()) + '%');
                }
            }
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            axis: 'left',
            title: 'Chrome',
            xField: 'month',
            yField: 'data3',
            style: {
                lineWidth: 4
            },
            marker: {
                radius: 4
            },
            highlight: {
                fillStyle: '#000',
                radius: 5,
                lineWidth: 2,
                strokeStyle: '#fff'
            },
            tooltip: {
                trackMouse: true,
                style: 'background: #fff',
                renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                    var title = item.series.getTitle();
                    this.setHtml(title + ' for ' + storeItem.get('month')
                        + ': ' + storeItem.get(item.series.getYField()) + '%');
                }
            }
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            axis: 'left',
            title: 'Safari',
            xField: 'month',
            yField: 'data4',
            style: {
                lineWidth: 4
            },
            marker: {
                radius: 4
            },
            highlight: {
                fillStyle: '#000',
                radius: 5,
                lineWidth: 2,
                strokeStyle: '#fff'
            },
            tooltip: {
                trackMouse: true,
                style: 'background: #fff',
                renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                    var title = item.series.getTitle();
                    this.setHtml(title + ' for ' + storeItem.get('month')
                        + ': ' + storeItem.get(item.series.getYField()) + '%');
                }
            }
        }]

    }]
});

function getStore() {
    return {
        fields: ['month', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4'],
        data: [{
            month: 'Jan',
            data1: 20,
            data2: 37,
            data3: 35,
            data4: 4
        }, {
            month: 'Feb',
            data1: 20,
            data2: 37,
            data3: 36,
            data4: 5
        }, {
            month: 'Mar',
            data1: 19,
            data2: 36,
            data3: 37,
            data4: 4
        }, {
            month: 'Apr',
            data1: 18,
            data2: 36,
            data3: 38,
            data4: 5
        }, {
            month: 'May',
            data1: 18,
            data2: 35,
            data3: 39,
            data4: 4
        }, {
            month: 'Jun',
            data1: 17,
            data2: 34,
            data3: 42,
            data4: 4
        }, {
            month: 'Jul',
            data1: 16,
            data2: 34,
            data3: 43,
            data4: 4
        }, {
            month: 'Aug',
            data1: 16,
            data2: 33,
            data3: 44,
            data4: 4
        }, {
            month: 'Sep',
            data1: 16,
            data2: 32,
            data3: 44,
            data4: 4
        }, {
            month: 'Oct',
            data1: 16,
            data2: 32,
            data3: 45,
            data4: 4
        }, {
            month: 'Nov',
            data1: 15,
            data2: 31,
            data3: 46,
            data4: 4
        }, {
            month: 'Dec',
            data1: 15,
            data2: 31,
            data3: 47,
            data4: 4
        }]
    };
};
```